# Calculating Complex integral ${\int _{_{_{\left|z\right|=\frac{1}{2}}}}}\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+1}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

I am trying to calculate the integral $${\int _{_{_{\left|z\right|=\frac{1}{2}}}}}\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+1}dz$$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$
According to answers, it is zero because it is a closed curve.
I tried to find the solution by brute force and got $2\pi i sin(t)$
My way of solution:
$${\int _{_{_{\left|z\right|=\frac{1}{2}}}}}\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+1}dz={\int _{_{_{\left|z\right|=\frac{1}{2}}}}}\frac{-e^{zt}}{\left(zi-1\right)\left(zi+1\right)}dz=\frac{1}{2}{\int _{_{_{\left|z\right|=\frac{1}{2}}}}}\frac{e^{zt}}{\left(zi+1\right)}dz-\frac{1}{2}{\int _{_{_{\left|z\right|=\frac{1}{2}}}}}\frac{e^{zt}}{\left(zi-1\right)}dz$$
which in fact is equal to:
$$\frac{\pi }{2i\pi }{\int _{_{_{\left|z\right|=\frac{1}{2}}}}}\frac{e^{zt}}{\left(z-i\right)}dz-\frac{\pi }{2\pi i}{\int _{_{_{\left|z\right|=\frac{1}{2}}}}}\frac{e^{zt}}{\left(z+i\right)}dz$$

Then, by using cauchy integral formula ( since $\gamma$ is a closed curve, derivative and $f(z)=e^{zt}$ is complete in complex ) I will receive:
$$\pi f\left(i\right)-\pi f\left(-i\right)\:=\:\pi e^{it}-\pi e^{-it}=\pi \left(e^{it}-e^{-it}\right)=2\pi i\sin\left(t\right)\ne 0$$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: It is zero because it is closed, rectifiable (and simple) curve, and because the integrand function is analytic on $\;|z|\le\frac12\;$ ...

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks! so if it was at domain of $|z|\ge 1$, would it be good? or $|z|>1$ only
EDIT: I got my answer, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,
$$
\int_{|z|=1/2}\frac{e^{zt}}{z\pm i}\,dz=0
$$
since $\pm i$ is lies *outside* the disk centered at $0$ with radius $\frac12$.

Note that it is *not* true that the integral of an analytic function along a closed curve is always $0$. This is true however when the domain of the function contains the region of $\mathbb{C}$ bounded by the curve.

Comment: Ohh I see
If the radius of the ball was $|z|>1$, would my answer be good?
And if it was $|z| \ge 1$, it would be still $0$ or my answer?

Comment: If $|z|=1$, then the question makes no sense, because $|\pm i|=1$. But, yes, what you wrote would be correct if the radius was greater than $1$.

Comment: Wait, by greater then 1, you mean without 1 right?
oh yea, at $|z|=1$ it is not good, cus the $denominator=0$
Thanks! I didnt notice that my domain was important